# export in js is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

It is a very small issue but I can't find out: I have 2 file in the same folder: config.js and server.js. The last one uses the config.js with the following code:

```
...
var config = ('./config');
...
//Configuration
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
mongoose.connect(config.database);
```

By running the server I have problem with connection due to a wrong address, infact the following error is shown

> MongoError: failed to connect to server [undefined:27017] on first connect ...

The config.js contains just:

```
module.exports = {
    'secret' : 'test123',
    'database' : 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test'
};
```

And If I replace the mongoose.connect with the following code

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test');
```

everything works fine... Why it can't resolve the database name?

Comment: `var config = ('./config');` -> `var config = require('./config');`

Comment: damn copy/past :D I think you are right ^^"

Comment: Use proper IDE, it would save you from this kind of bullshit problems.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions? Actually im running it in a ubuntu 16.04 server (no graphic). And it is hosted in as a virtual machine on my windows computer. The code is in a sharing directory

Comment: @dfsq webstorm, i love it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must to use `var config = require(./config.js)` and config.js must be on the same dir if you do that, the problem is you forgot `require`